# Know the key for the selected item, Theme vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, customization

I am new to theme creation, and would like to know if there is a developer tool to inspect the key to change the color of a specific element. Something similar to the browser inspector.

Comment: `Developer : Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

Comment: @Mark but not only inspect the editor, also all the other elements like terminal,side bar, status bar etc etc

Comment: open the json file and use the intellisense to show all the possible theme names to use

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. Unfortunately, for colors of VSCode, you'll have to search yourself in:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Answer (score 0):

Cmd+shift+P and Run this command "Toggle developer tools" to get a chrome inspect sidebar, from there you can view the "--vscode-..." css variable that the element gets it's "color" style from (you can look at the computed styles and expand "color") and that will be the key value you're looking for.